# What is the speech in the background at the end of the "Iron Sky" movie?

Tags: movie, iron-sky

During the scene with the slow motion space explosions, some man can be heard giving some kind of speech in the background but I didn't understand what it was and what was it about.  Does  anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's part of Laibach's music lyric titled *America*:

> We, children
>   We, children, are born in Sin
>   We are born in Sin.
>   That is why we must let
>   The Light, The light of God
>   into our hearts, Children
>   We are all Children of God,
>   but to the whole we are Sinners
>   We are Sinners
>   We must let the Light,
>   let the Love of God
>   the Eternal Love of God
>   into our hearts or we will Burn
>   Burn in Hell
>   Burn in Eternal Damnation

Comment: thanks very much, also for making me discover laibach :)

Answer (score 4):

The Sermon (of to me an unknown (tele)evangelist) reads as follows:

We children,

We children are born of Sin.

We are born of Sin.

That is why we must let

The Light of God, the Light of God

Into our hearts, children.

We are all Children of God,

But to the Lord we are Sinners.

We are Sinners.

We must let the Light, let the Love of God,

The Eternal Love of God into our hearts.

Or we will Burn

Burn in Hell.

Burn in Eternal Damnation.

Answer (score 2):

The song - played twice during Iron Sky - that begins with the heavy bass is from the song "America" by the Slovenian industrial band Laibach. Laibach made the soundtrack for Iron Sky. The quote "We children, we children are born of sin, we are born of sin and that's why we must let the light of God, the light of God in your hearts children. We all are children of God, but no we are sinners! We are sinners, we most let the light, let the love of God, the eternal love of God into our hearts or we will burn, burn in hell, burn in eternal damnation." is part of that song. As I interpret the song, it is that, The United States in need of a mutual identity for all of their citizens to identify with, turns to fundamentalist Christianity.

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct, but it's identical to the answer already posted by @meonx-item.

Comment: @phantom42: actually, this answer does add *some* new information, namely that the band is Slovenian. (It also adds some interpretation that sounds irrelevant to me, but I've never so much as heard of this movie.)